# matching algorithm to match two set of strings

Tags: algorithm, pattern-matching, string-matching

1. there are  two sets of strings.
2. each string has two parts.
3. each string in the first set to be matched to some string of other set.
4. each string has **at most** 1 counter part in the next set.
5. a string may not have any match in the other set.
6. same goes with the other set. if string in set two is matched to a string in set one. it cannot be matched to any other string.
   i need a matching algorithm to match these two sets.

Comment: how is machine learning in this problem involved? Isn't it accurate for use of regular expresions?

Comment: Can you give an example? E.g. I don't get what you mean by item 2.

Comment: And please explain your matching criterion. Is it exact matching of characters between strings, or are we doing approximate matchings (similar to a clustering)?

Comment: Is there a training set?  (This problem had the tag "machine learning" until lejlot edited it).  It sounds like you're describing a typical problem solved with a naive Bayes classifier.

Comment: sorry i don't think this falls to machine learning. i was confused. and it is like a closest match.

Answer (score 1):

1) is necessary for you 2 for cicle:
2) 1 index in the first word 
3) 1 index in the second word
4) you must to confron for every time the letter in the first word with all letter in the second word

Answer (score 0):

You can:

1. Sort the sets (`O(n log n) + O(m log m)`)
2. Go through each sorted list and check if there is a match (`O(n + m)`)

Overall complexity is `O(max(n,m) log(max(n,m)))`

Comment: those string might not be exactly same. they might be similar

Answer (score 0):

Your description isn't very clear.
If you wanted a function that compared both sets with each string in the other set, apart from the string itself...
Then try this?

```
def search(set1, set2):
    for astring in set1:
        for anotherstring in set2:
            if astring == anotherstring:
                pass
            else:
                Do something
```

Or any variation of the function?
This answer may be completely wrong i understand, but i THINK i got what you meant?

Comment: those string might not be exactly same. they might be similar.

Comment: define similar, what is allowed: insertions, deletions, mismatches, inversions?

Comment: as i said each string has two parts. those sub strings are modified a little.may be one sub string remains same and the other is changed.